# How to set different customizing for vi and vim

Tags: linux

I'm using both vim and vi and I want to set different sitting (front, line number etc...). I read that I could do that using my ~/.exrc and ~/.vimrc by using in my ~/.vimrc:

source ~/.exrc
or
so exrc

but none of them worked. Do you know how I could do that?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, your vi is just a symbolic link to vim. If that is the case, there's no way to distinguish how it was called. What you can do is alias vi to something like

```
vim -u ~/.exrc
```

in your bash(or whatever shell)rc.

This would look like:

```
alias vi="vim -u ~/.exrc"
```

-u makes vim load without any initializations except the one specified in the argument (so it will skip .vimrc).

If you want to find out if your vi is just an alias to vim, do something like this:

```
which vi
```

then, for whatever it says it's a symbolic link to, do

```
file <insert symbolic link path>
```

Keep doing that until it tells you it's an executable. Then repeat the same process for vim and see if the final executables are the same or not.

Comment: Dear, actually my vi was a symbolic link to vim. I followed your instruction and it worked. Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

actually my vi was a symbolic link to vim. I followed your instruction and it worked. 
Best regards